# Obtaining the Identity of a Reviewer

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am getting the Policy Configurations (GET [https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/policy/configurations](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/policy/configurations)) and for the policy of type "Required reviewers" (response array item's type.displayName), there is a property named "ReviewerIds" which is an array of what looks like GUIDs.

However, I do not know how to retrieve information about the user(s) or user group(s) identified by the GUID(s) in that array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you're looking either for IdentityByID or IdentityByDescriptor:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/ims/identities/read-identities?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP#by-ids
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/ims/identities/read-identities?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP#by-identitydescriptors

Be sure to call the right endpoint, identity information is from `https://vssps.dev.azure.com`.